# Why use null in r

Tags: r, null

What is different between this two statement in R or why use NULL in R ?

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    T[i]="a"
}
T
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

by using NULL

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    T=NULL
    T[i]="a"
}
T
[1] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "a"
```

Comment: `T=NULL` should be outside and before the `for()` loop to initialize the variable `T`.  But since `T` is an R global variable representing `TRUE`, you are not seeing what actually happens in the first loop.  Try using something other than `T`, like `x`, and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

Simply in second code you are assigning T=`NULL` so all the previous states will be lost but at the last step after assigning `NULL` to T, loop will assign `a` to last index of T, hence the output

```
for (i in 1:10) { # consider last step of loop
     T=NULL  # set T=NULL so all values are gone
     T[i]="a" # set last index of T = 'a'
 }
 T
```

About first case it will run as usual which i guess you already know.